# Loop through JS objects and check if properties are null

Tags: javascript

Trying to find an easy way to loop through an object structure to build queryString to pass to my API endpoint.

Scenario -- Is if `id` is null use `codes` or `sku` or if `codes and sku` are null then use `id`, instead of using multiple `if()` to do this conditions is there a better way to achieve this? If all are present then should default to using `sku`

```js
var loopThrough = {
            "OrderLine": [{
                "Product": {
                    "Id": null,
                    "Codes": ["1112"],
                    "Sku": "CS1112"
                },
                "TotalValue": 0,
                "Quantity": 1
            }, {
                "Product": {
                    "Id": null,
                    "Codes": ["1113"],
                    "Sku": "CS1113"
                },
                "TotalValue": 0,
                "Quantity": 1
            }],
            "OriginatingSite": {
                "Id": 1
            },
            "TotalValue": 0
        };

        var allIds = '?';
        var first = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < loopThrough.OrderLine.length; i++) {
            var orderLines = loopThrough.OrderLine[i];
            var prodId = orderLines.Product.Id;
            var prodCodes = orderLines.Product.Codes;
            var prodSku = orderLines.Product.Sku;
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                if (prodId === null) {
                    allIds = allIds + "&code=" + orderLines.Product.Codes[0];
                } else {
                    allIds = allIds + "&id=" + orderLines.Product.Id;
                }
            } else {
                if (prodId !== null) {
                    allIds = allIds + "&id=" + orderLines.Product.Id
                } else {
                    allIds = allIds + "&sku=" + orderLines.Product.Sku;
                }
            }
            console.log(allIds)
        }
```

Comment: What if none of them are null!

Comment: Ah it would then default to `sku`, edited my question added default scenario

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot to change, anything more complex will kind of ruini the whole point. But you can be more 'loose' on your conditionals, if they are a priority of themselves.

```js
var loopThrough = {
            "OrderLine": [{
                "Product": {
                    "Id": null,
                    "Codes": ["1112"],
                    "Sku": "CS1112"
                },
                "TotalValue": 0,
                "Quantity": 1
            }, {
                "Product": {
                    "Id": null,
                    "Codes": ["1113"],
                    "Sku": "CS1113"
                },
                "TotalValue": 0,
                "Quantity": 1
            }],
            "OriginatingSite": {
                "Id": 1
            },
            "TotalValue": 0
        };

        var allIdsArr = [];
        var first = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < loopThrough.OrderLine.length; i++) {
            var orderLines = loopThrough.OrderLine[i];
            var prodId = orderLines.Product.Id;
            var prodCodes = orderLines.Product.Codes;
            var prodSku = orderLines.Product.Sku;

            allIdsArr.push(
                prodId !== null ? 'id=' + prodId :
                prodCodes !== null ? 'code=' + prodCodes :
                'sku=' + prodSku
            )
        }

        console.log('?' + allIdsArr.join('&'))
```

Answer (score 0):

- don't do effectively the same comparison two different ways, it makes the code very hard to read.
- don't use `for` loop unless you have to, use `map`
- don't declare variables you don't intend to use
- when code must go down two different paths, minimize the length of the different paths.

A short version might be:

```js
const loopThrough = {
            "OrderLine": [{
                "Product": {
                    "Id": null,
                    "Codes": ["1112"],
                    "Sku": "CS1112"
                },
                "TotalValue": 0,
                "Quantity": 1
            }, {
                "Product": {
                    "Id": null,
                    "Codes": ["1113"],
                    "Sku": "CS1113"
                },
                "TotalValue": 0,
                "Quantity": 1
            }],
            "OriginatingSite": {
                "Id": 1
            },
            "TotalValue": 0
        };
    const url = "?" +
      loopThrough.OrderLine
        .map((order, index) => {
          const product = order.Product;
          return product.Id?
            `id=${product.Id}`:
            index === 0? 
              `sku=${product.Sku}`: 
              `code=${product.Codes[0]}`;
        })
        .join("&");
        console.log(url);
```

Comment: could you add it as snippets so it can be tested, thanks